# VS Code: Is there a way to refactor class and file name at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code, refactoring

I use Typescript and refactor classnames a lot.

Right now I have to rename file and class names separately.

Is there any extension / shortcut for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any shortcut allowing this. Nothing is linking the typescript filename and the class name for now.

Some people are looking for the same behavior over there and created a feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10218. Check it out :)